# Grammar to parse module specification

Tags: raku

Raku modules can be specified in different ways, for example:

`MyModule`

`MyModule:ver<1.0.3>`

`MyModule:ver<1.0.3>:auth<Name  (email@example.com)>;`

`MyModule:ver<1.0.3>:auth<Name  <email@example.com>>;`

I wrote the below `grammar` to parse the module spec which works fine for most of specs but it fails if the `auth` field contains `<` or `>`. How can I fix the grammar to match in this case as well?

I can't figure out how to say match everything in between `<`  and `>` including any `<` and `>` as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

grammar Spec {

  token TOP { <spec> }

  token spec { <name> <keyval>* }

  token name { [<-[./:<>()\h]>+]+ % '::' }

  token keyval { ':' <key> <value> }

  proto token key { * }
  token key:sym<ver>     { <sym> }
  token key:sym<version> { <sym> }
  token key:sym<auth>    { <sym> }
  token key:sym<api>     { <sym> }
  token key:sym<from>    { <sym> }

  # BUG: fix specs that contains '<>' inside value;
  token value { '<' ~ '>' $<val>=<-[<>]>* | '(' ~ ')' $<val>=<-[()]>* }

}

my \tests = (
  'MyModule:ver<1.0.3>:auth<Name (email@example.com)>',
  'MyModule:ver<1.0.3>:auth<Name <email@example.com>>',
);

for tests -> \spec {

  say so Spec.parse: spec;

}

# Output:
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks Jo King, I would like to mark the question as solved with your comment, care to post the comment as answer?

Comment: Note this grammar has many issues. First the restricted tokens are more strict than needed as evident by `package ::("Foo.Bar") { }` (theoretically `use foo.bar:from<Java>`). Secondly it attempts to parse non-constant version definitions which require evaluating code. Third it will break as soon as any new attribute is added (or even existing ones such as `:file<...>`). Fourth it doesn't consider escaping of `<` or `>`.

Comment: Thanks ugexe for pointing these out, working on fixing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know that the inner field will basically be in the same format as the value token, you can recursively match for value with `$<val>=[.*? <value>?]`. This even lets you capture the contents of the inner field seperately:

```
token value { '<' ~ '>' $<val>=[.*? <value>?] | '(' ~ ')' $<val>=<-[()]>* }
```

If you don't want the inner contents than you can use the recursive `<~~>` in place of `<value>`

```
token value { '<' ~ '>' $<val>=[.*? <~~>?] | '(' ~ ')' $<val>=<-[()]>* }
```

Comment: I recommend against using `.*?`, and instead use `<-[>]>*` (everything except `>`) inside token `value`. Otherwise you can erroneously match strings like `<abc>def>` .